# Whether to use dropout vs. batch normalization vs L1/L2 loss for regularization

Tags: neural-networks, regularization

I am familiar with how dropout, batch normalization, and L1/L2 loss all work. However, I do not have an intuitive sense on when to use which and what parameters to pass in. I know I can do grid search on this, but is there a more intuitive decision i can make?

Because even if I do grid search, here's my search space:

1. Apply dropout on every **combination** of layers
2. For each of these combinations, vary the dropout amount from $0.01$ to $0.5$ with $0.05$ increments.
3. Add batch normalization on every combination of layers
4. Combining batch and dropout
5. Using L1 and L2 on every combo of layers
6. Varying L1 and L2 rates at all these combos.

The trend seems to be to just use the method that's been published by the state-of-the-art networks. However, NNs are such a black box that it's very possible for different combinations to work  better for different problems.

Hence, can someone share some theory/intuition on how combine these 3 techniques, what type of problems to apply them on, etc. It'd make for a really cool canonical post.

I'm particularly interested in applications of these techniques in segmentation networks such as FCNs.